# How to include include whether users account enabled for Springboot User authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have this function that does authentication for user. However, I have a `userActive` as a field that I want to include in the authentication. So see whether the user's account is enabled.

`userActive` is a `Boolean`

How would I able to do that?

```
override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String?): UserDetails {
        var user: User = userRepository.findByEmail(username!!)
        if (user == null) {
            throw UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.")
        }
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthorities(
                user.getRoles()!!
            )
        )
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another constructor of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` available:

```java
new User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities)
```

The 3rd parameter, `enabled` seems to correspond to your `userActive` field.

Keep in mind that a disabled user returns `false` for the `isEnabled()` check after authentication. This will result in an error being delegated to your configured `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, which will appear as a failed authentication.

Comment: Sure thing. Mind accepting the answer? :D